# While loop not exiting when value changing from False to True

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basic Tic-Tac-Toe game. I have everything running except I am having trouble with the `check_for_winner` function. No matter what I do I can't get the code to exit the function once `a = True`. Without the while loop or with. How can I get the code to stop checking every single possible instance once a winner has been detected?

I've tried setting `a == False`, I've tried it without the while statement which gets rid of the looping but doesn't get it to exit out when the condition is met.

```
def check_for_winner():
  a = False
  while a is False:
    for x in range(3):
      if print(grid[x] == grid[x+3] and grid[x+3] == grid[x+6]):
        a = True
        return a
    for x in range(0,7,3):
      if print(grid[x] == grid[x+1] and grid[x+1] == grid[x+2]):
        a = True
        return a
    if print((grid[0] == grid[4] and grid[4] == grid[8]) or (grid[2] == 
        grid[4] and grid[4] == grid[6])):
      a = True
      return a
```

It should exit the while loop once one the conditions is met but it continues to loop through. Instead of exiting then printing who one it prints True the False six times, repeating.

Comment: What does `if print(...)` mean? (Hint: it has no meaning.)

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the variable `a` entirely.

Comment: `a is False` should have been written `a == False`. Or even better, `not a`. (Or even better: get rid of the while loop since it doesn't appear to be doing anything...!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is all the unnecessary calls to `print()`. They're all returning `None` which causes the `if` checks to all be equivalent to `if None:`. Get rid of them.

```
def check_for_winner():
  a = False
  while a is False:
    for x in range(3):
      if grid[x] == grid[x+3] and grid[x+3] == grid[x+6]:
        a = True
        return a
    for x in range(0,7,3):
      if grid[x] == grid[x+1] and grid[x+1] == grid[x+2]:
        a = True
        return a
    if (grid[0] == grid[4] and grid[4] == grid[8]) or (grid[2] == 
        grid[4] and grid[4] == grid[6]):
      a = True
      return a
  return False
```

Then you can get rid of the unnecessary `a` variable and the `while` loop.

```
def check_for_winner():
  for x in range(3):
    if grid[x] == grid[x+3] and grid[x+3] == grid[x+6]:
      return True
  for x in range(0,7,3):
    if grid[x] == grid[x+1] and grid[x+1] == grid[x+2]:
      return True
  if (grid[0] == grid[4] and grid[4] == grid[8]) or (grid[2] == 
      grid[4] and grid[4] == grid[6]):
    return True
  return False
```

You can also use comparison chaining to replace `foo == bar and bar == baz` with `foo == bar == baz`.

```
def check_for_winner():
  for x in range(3):
    if grid[x] == grid[x+3] == grid[x+6]:
      return True
  for x in range(0,7,3):
    if grid[x] == grid[x+1] == grid[x+2]:
      return True
  if grid[0] == grid[4] == grid[8] or grid[2] == grid[4] == grid[6]:
    return True
  return False
```